# External hard drive won't show up on finder (theres more to this)

Tags: finder, hard-drive, external-disk, trash

So I plugged in my hard drive, and deleted a file on it, a **.nfo** file. I forgot I had a file in the trash and so when I ejected the disk, my mac prompted me an alert like "disk is in use" with a force eject button. I force ejected without thinking, because I really didn't think any of my files were in use (I checked the usual places like whether a video file was playing somewhere etc.) When I try to plug it back, I realise it doesn't read or appear on finder. I've restarted my computer and still nothing. Other hard drives work so its definitely an isolated problem. Any ideas?

Update: I can't do a Disk Utility repair? the option isn't even available

Comment: A file in the Trash wouldn't be the cause of the 'disk in use' message. Each drive has its own trash folder.

Comment: Does it show in Terminal? Connect the drive, and do `diskutil list`.

Comment: it shows up on the terminal!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see your drive in Disk Utility, even though the data may be corrupted, so you may need to wipe the drive in order to make it usable again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but are there ways to save the disk? I mean I'm not a computer expert but for real though, can one simple mishap like this screw up my whole disk?? I'm at disk utility now and I don't know what I'm doing really.. lol

Comment: @SamuelXun I'm not sure. In Disk Utility, select the drive, then select Repair Permissions. That might work, but if it doesn't, your local computer repair shop or Apple Store should be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

The solution of this problem can be `chkdsk` command from windows.
It doesn't require admin privilegies, so you can do this at work

Connect your disk at Windows PC. It will appear as `[drive letter]`

Press Win-R, and then type `chkdisk [drive letter]: /f` Press Enter.

When the process finishes, safely remove disk through windows tray and, have a happy day!